# writing urlpattern in django for rendering an image

Tags: python, django, url-pattern

in my `django` app,I have an `index` page which lists some summary info which is dynamic(based on some user input data in db) . I have coded it as below

views.py

```
def custom_render(request,context,template):
    req_context=RequestContext(request,context)
    return render_to_response(template,req_context)

@login_required
def index(request, template_name):
    summary_info = get_summary(...)
    return custom_render(request,{'summary':summary_info},template_name)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns=patterns('', 
     ...
    url(r'^$', 'myapp.views.index',dict(template_name = 'myapp/index.html'), name = 'home'),
...
```

Now,I want to include a chart image generated by matplotlib on the home page..So,when user requests the index page url, he can see both the summary info and the chart

I have written the index.html as below

```
{% extends "myapp/base.html" %}
....
<div id='summary'>
{# here display the summary #}
...
</div>

<div id='chart'>
<img class="chartimage"src="{% url myapp_render_chart %}"            
    alt="chart"            
   />
</div>
```

The chart view is

```
def render_chart(request):
    data = get_data(request.user)
    canvas = None
    if data:
        canvas = create_piechart(data)
    response = HttpResponse(content_type = 'image/png')
    if canvas:
        canvas.print_png(response)
    return response

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def create_piechart(data,chartsize=(16,16)):
    ...
    figure = plt.figure(figsize = chartsize)
    plt.pie(fracs, labels=labels, autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True)        
    canvas = FigureCanvas(figure)
    plt.close(figure)
    return canvas
```

I am not sure how I should do the urlmapping.The url `r'^$',` is already mapped to the index page.But I need to create a `url(...)` in `urlpatterns` sothat the view render_chart() is associated with the name `myapp_render_chart` and so can be called within `{% url %}` tag . Can someone pls help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you just want another url mapping? It wouldn't be very different from the one you already have. e.g.:

```
urlpatterns = patterns("myapp.views",
    url(r'^$', 'index',dict(template_name = 'myapp/index.html'), name = 'home'),
    url(r'^kick-ass-chart/$', 'render_chart', name='myapp_render_chart'),
)
```

Comment: thanks Ciske,I was doubtful about putting a `kick-ass-chart` url regex which would never be used.